# How to tell py.test to skip certain directories?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I tried to use the [`norecursedirs`](http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html#confval-norecursedirs) option inside setup.cfg to tell py.test not to collect tests from certain directories but it seems it does ignore it.

```
[tool:pytest]
norecursedirs=lib/third
```

When I run `py.test` I do see how it does get tests from inside `lib/third`!

Comment: It seems that I have `py.test` and `pytest` both of them runnings tests and being different beasts. Strange but `pytest` is the one failing because it does not load the exclusions from `[pytest]`.

Comment: `pytest` is from logilab.  You want `py.test`.

Comment: also try doing `nosecuredirs=lib/third/*`

Comment: is there a way to ignore some folders in the script itself with code ?

Comment: ended up here because I was curious why the hell my pytest of web app in local development are so extremly slow... The reason was some uploaded resources directory with nested yy/dd/mm structure.... causing it reallly sucks! thankfully `[pytest] norecursedirs = resources` in `pytest.ini` does a trick!

Comment: @ecatmur I guess your comment is outdated? I think today, one should use `pytest` instead of `py.test`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved the mystery: If a pytest section is found in one of the possible config files (`pytest.ini`, `tox.ini` and `setup.cfg`), pytest will not look for any others so be sure you define the py.test options in a single file.

I would suggest using `setup.cfg`.

Comment: Why `setup.cfg`? The current documentation appears to recommend [the other two](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#ini-options-ref)

Comment: i think it's important to mention that if you want to use a `.ini` file you need to specify it with `pytest -c pytest.ini`. for some reason `setup.cfg` contents were picked up automatically.

Comment: @therightstuff For me `pytest.ini` is used without such tricks.

Answer (score 189):

`py.test --ignore=somedir` worked for me

In pytest.ini:

```ini
[pytest]
addopts = --ignore=somedir --ignore=someotherdir
```

Comment: And `--ignore` can be specified multiple times to ignore multiple directories

Comment: How to skip certain tests instead of directory

Comment: You can use the `-k` option as another answer below shows. See "Run tests by keyword expressions" on https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests.  Marks may be helpful here as well. Mark your tests as "slow", etc and then use `-k "not slow"`

Comment: It is also possible [to use `--ignore-glob`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/pythoncollection.html#ignore-paths-during-test-collection) to ignore test file paths based on Unix shell-style wildcards. E.g. `--ignore-glob=**/sandbox/*` will ignore all files in any `sandbox` folder.

Answer (score 64):

If you have several directories with different parents you can specify different `--ignore` parameters:

`py.test --ignore=somedir --ignore=otherdir --ignore=etcdir`

> - new option: --ignore will prevent specified path from collection.
>     Can be specified multiple times.

Answer (score 26):

You can use

```
py.test -k 'not third'
```

that excludes all 'third' directory contents.

Answer (score 19):

In my case, the issue was the missing wildcard. The following works for me:

```
[tool:pytest]
norecursedirs = subpath/*
```

whereas just `norecursedirs = subpath` didn't.

Comment: Same here. Very strange behavior though.

Comment: Looks like those entries are just globs, not foldernames, then. Note you can add more entries with a space after each.

Comment: does it support pattern such as `a/**/test*.py`?

Comment: for me addition of the asterisk is unnecessary, it works without it

Comment: is the folder path absolute or relative to pytest entry point ?

Comment: @matanster Perhaps pytest's behavior has changed in the meantime?

Comment: @Pierrick Rambaud: I'd always assume relative, not absolute. If one would commit an absolute path to a version control system, it would only work in this particular absolute checkout path.

Answer (score 12):

`norecursedirs` should work.  Check whether you have a pytest.ini or other setup.cfg files.  How are you invoking `py.test`?

Comment: I do have `setup.cfg` with the proper `[pytest]` and norecorsedirs inside but it seems to be ignored, and instead it will look for all files.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using setup.cfg, you have to use `[tool:pytest]` as per [http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

> # content of pytest.ini
>   # can also be defined in tox.ini or setup.cfg file, although the section
>   # name in setup.cfg files should be "tool:pytest"

Answer (score 5):

To use `pytest.ini` (which is recommended, unless you're using `tox` in which case `tox.ini` would make sense), call `pytest` with `pytest -c pytest.ini`.

In order to prevent my sample `not_me_1.py` and `not_me_2.py` from being tested or linted, my `pytest.ini` is as follows:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --ignore-glob=not_me_*

[pycodestyle]
ignore = not_me_* ALL
```

Answer (score -1):

This (regex pattern) worked for me in pytest.ini:

```
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:.*(venv)*
```

you can also do this:

```
filterwarnings =
    ignore:::.*(venv)*
```

or to be more specific with libraries, you can do:

```
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:pkg_resources.*
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:django.*
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:rest_framework_simplejwt.*
```

Comment: it's counter-productive to run tests and then simply ignore them. The OP isn't talking about ignoring warnings, but skipping tests.