# pytest ignore venv when called from shell without pytest.ini file

Tags: python, pytest, site-packages

I am trying to use `pytest` within my Mac's terminal.  I do not have a `pytest.ini` set up, and do not wish to make one at this time.

When I run the command `pytest` alone, it prints warnings (`DeprecationWarning`) for multiple site packages within my virtual environment (named `venv`, located within my project's root directory).

```
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py:1
  /path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp
```

I would like to ignore the `venv/` directory when running `pytest`, so my warnings are relevant to my project only.

**How can I *not* run `pytest` on my virtual environment?**

---

**What I Have Tried**

I have tried multiple versions of the `--ignore` flag:

```bash
pytest --ignore=venv
pytest --ignore=./venv/
pytest --ignore="venv/*"
pytest --ignore="./venv/*"
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571520/11163122))

And using `-k`

```bsh
pytest -k 'not venv'
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24625380/11163122))

---

**What I Have Read**

`--disable-pytest-warnings`: I still want other warnings to be displayed

`--pythonwarnings ignore::DeprecationWarning` seems too generic (what if one of my project files uses a deprecated module)

`--pythonwarnings ignore::DeprecationWarning:some_package.*:` is too manual (lots of my site packages generate warnings)

---

**Versioning**

- `macOS Mojave v10.14.3`
- `Python 3.6.5`
- `pytest==5.3.5`

Comment: That warning is not emitted by pytest. It's emitted from the `imp` module when `eventlet` imports it. Use one of the solutions you have already discovered.

Comment: Have you tried `pytest --ignore=venv/`? What if you specify the folder that pytest has to look at (`pytest <folder>`)? Would that be an option?