# How to skip testcases in jenkins nightly build

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, groovy

I have some testcases in python selenium framework that run on specific environment so I want to skip those testcases in nightly run.
[image]
here I want to skip METs folder.

I made changes in Jenkins groovy file with --ignore and --exclude syntax however I am getting error. "error: unknown option `ignore'

if( params.ENVIRONMENT == 'cores'){

bat label: '', script: 'git checkout %BRANCHNAME% & git pull origin %BRANCHNAME% "C:\Users\selenium\Python\Python39\Scripts\py.test" **--ignore-glob=**/METS/*** -s --browser %BROWSER% --html=\\kannfssvm0x.furry.abc.com\data\abc\Selenium\Reports\%BUILD_NUMBER%\pyresults.html --baseURL "https://%ENVIRONMENT%.abc.com/cms/servlet/cms.servlet.Login?locale=en&licenseeParam=asc" -n %CONCURRENCY%'

what syntax should I add to skip that folder when run on specific environment?

Comment: Instead of using --ignore-glob, you can use the --ignore option followed by the specific directory or file you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this link : [How to tell py.test to skip certain directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117062/how-to-tell-py-test-to-skip-certain-directories)

Instead of using --ignore-glob, you can use the --ignore option followed by the specific directory or file you want to skip.

```
if (params.ENVIRONMENT == 'cores') {
    bat label: '', script: 'git checkout %BRANCHNAME% & git pull origin %BRANCHNAME% "C:\Users\selenium\Python\Python39\Scripts\py.test" --ignore=/METS/*** -s --browser %BROWSER% --html=\\kannfssvm0x.furry.abc.com\data\abc\Selenium\Reports\%BUILD_NUMBER%\pyresults.html --baseURL "https://%ENVIRONMENT%.abc.com/cms/servlet/cms.servlet.Login?locale=en&licenseeParam=asc" -n %CONCURRENCY%'
}
```