# how to ignore folders contained in tests with pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I checked the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117062/how-to-tell-py-test-to-skip-certain-directories) and it's many answers. It's very outdated (as OP is referencing py.test) and no answer is specific enough for my use case.

I have the following test structure:

```
.
└── tests/
    ├── test_number/
    │   ├── test_Number.py
    │   └── test_Float.py
    └── legacy/
        ├── test_toto.py
        ├── ...
        └── test_tutu.py
```

I want to run my test with a simple command to avoid any issues of reproducibility in downstream pipelines or local dev.

```
pytest
```

So I want pytest to avoid the entire content of the legacy folder.

I'm using a `pyproject.toml` configuration so as per the recommendation of pytest docs I wrote:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = "tests"
norecursedirs = "tests/legacy/*"
```

Problem, the file are still parsed and tested. I also tried to make the path relative to the testpaths and I got the same result.

Comment: The answer in the mentioned question is still valid, e.g. using `addopts = --ignore=tests/legacy` in the respective section in pyproject.yaml should work. See also [the documentstion](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#configuration-options).